# How can I create two beans of same class in a Spring Context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

I can declare a bean in Spring using @Bean annotation. Let's say I declare two beans of String type in my Application Context.

```
@Bean
public String country(){ return "India";}

@Bean
public String continent(){ return "Asia";}
```

In this case what will happen when the Spring Container will boot strap? Would  there be any error?

Comment: There wont be any error, you will have two beans named `country` and `continent` with type `String`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [define two beans of same class in single application context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324508/define-two-beans-of-same-class-in-single-application-context)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Two spring beans can be created in same context. But they need to be created in separate @Configuration files and separate access.

Comment: Two beans with same class don't needed to be in different configuration class.

Answer (score 3):

You can have beans of the same type in the same context. Both beans will have a different name (`country` and `continent`) derived from the method names:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public String country() {
        return "Germany";
    }
    @Bean
    public String continent() {
        return "Europe";
    }
}
```

Therefore you can wire the beans by name:

```
@Autowired
String country;

@Autowired
String continent;
```

You can also define a name explicitly if needed:

```
@Bean(name = "myContinent")
public String continent() {
    return "Europe";
}
```

And then wire using the `@Qualifier`:

```
@Qualifier("myContinent")
@Autowired
String continent;
```